# Is it possible to move data between two distributed tables in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I think the answer is no, but wanted to check here to be sure.
Is it possible to move data (copy and then delete the source) between two distributed tables in ClickHouse?
Say, I have local tables `a` and `b` defined in all of my nodes, and `a_dist` defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a_dist ON CLUSTER my_cluster_name AS a ENGINE = Distributed(my_cluster_name, default, a, rand())
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS b_dist ON CLUSTER my_cluster_name AS a ENGINE = Distributed(my_cluster_name, default, b, rand())
```

Is it possible to move all of the data from `a_dist` to `b_dist` directly? Or should I move data in each node from table `a` to table `b`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way

```sql
INSERT INTO b_dist SELECT * FROM a_dist;
TRUNCATE default.a ON CLUSTER 'my_cluster_name';
```

But it will produce numerous data transfer between the node where you execute this query and other nodes in cluster

for Atomic database engine and clickhouse 21.8+, run directly on each node will much faster

```sql
EXCHANGE TABLES default.a AND default.b
```